# Cannot record in Java in Android

Tags: java, android

Why can't I record my sound in java in android ?

```
MediaRecorder mr = new MediaRecorder(); 
try {
    File output = new File(path + "aa.wav");
    mr.setOutputFile(output);
    mr.prepare();
    mr.start();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
        mr.stop();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This code cannot compile because of i have "cannot resolve method setOutPutFile(java.io.File)"

and when I try it

```
 mr.setOutputFile("./a.wav");
```

I have: Cannot read file (permission denied)

but it is not logical because i added permission of external storage in the android.manifest file

```
<permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: You should also add your manifest file so we can see the permissions added

Comment: `./a.wav` does not point anywhere. Always use a method on `Context` or `Environment` to get a root directory. Assuming that `path` is something generated from one of those methods, use `File output = new File(path, "aa.wav");` and `mr.setOutputFile(output.getAbsolutePath());`.

Comment: Han I do exactly what you want `mr.setOutputFile(output.getAbsolutePath());`  i have: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/rec/b.wav: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)

Comment: Now, i have java.io.FileNotFoundException: /data/aa.wav: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)